# How do the electrons in an electron gun (used in CRT) compare to electrons in lightning or Tesla coil?

Tags: electricity

Is it also the same electrons that surround the nucleus of an atom?

Comment: An electron is an electron is an electron…

Comment: @JonCuster not always: electrons in a crystal (as in semiconductor physics) are quasiparticles which are different from vacuum electrons.

Comment: @Lambda What exactly difference between electrons in the three cases you mentioned do you expect? Generally, yes, all these electrons are the same objects. But maybe you are thinking of some particular case where it appears to be otherwise?

Comment: @Ruslan - just because they are in a potential doesn’t mean they aren’t real electrons. Is the electron in a hydrogen atom a quasiparticle?

Comment: @JonCuster it's not the potential that makes the difference. The principal difference stems from the mean field approximation: when we talk e.g. about band structure of silicon, we are discussing states of a quasiparticle—electron in crystal—which represents collective motion of all the electrons as a single quasi-electron in the field of all the nuclei and the remaining electrons. This model doesn't describe e.g. scattering of an electron by another electron (this is included in the mean field in an "average" way).

Comment: @Ruslan - how we decide to do a calculation has little to do with whether an electron is an electron. Mother Nature does not care how we try to make her problems tractable.

Comment: @JonCuster again, what we are talking about here is a model. Whether nature cares or doesn't care about it is irrelevant. A single-electron in crystal is a model that differs from a vacuum electron.